# Android SQLite issue - table … has no column named

Tags: android

Here i am getting data from Json using assets folder after i inserted into Data Base. Here is my code i am getting error no colum named.please,some help

```
 // StationDataBase     
           public class StationDataBase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
                // create database version
                public static final int Data_Base_Version = 2;
                // create database name
                public static final String Data_Base_Name = "sationDetails.db";
                // create database table name Sation Table
                public static final String Data_Base_Table_Name = "StaionTable";
                // create Station Table Columns names
                public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
                public static final String KEY_TRAIN_CODE = "trainCode";
                public static final String KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME = "trainStationName";

                public StationDataBase(Context context) {
                    super(context, Data_Base_Name, null, Data_Base_Version);
                    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                }

                // creating table
                @Override
                public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String CREATE_STATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + Data_Base_Table_Name
                            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TRAIN_CODE
                            + " TEXT," + KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME + " TEXT" + ")";

                    Log.e("DATA BASE CREATED", "CREATED" + CREATE_STATION_TABLE);
                    db.execSQL(CREATE_STATION_TABLE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                    db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXITS" + Data_Base_Table_Name);
                    onCreate(db);
                }

                public void insertData(String station_code, String name) {
                    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    // values.put("id", id);
                    values.put("KEY_TRAIN_CODE", station_code);
                    values.put("KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME", name);
                    Log.e("code", "insert into db" + station_code);
                    Log.e("code", "insert into db" + name);
                    dataBase.insert(Data_Base_Table_Name, null, values);
                }
            public ArrayList<String> getData() {
                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String data = "SELECT * FROM " + Data_Base_Table_Name;
                    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(data, null);
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {
                            // arrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                            arrayList.add(cursor.getString(0));
                            arrayList.add(cursor.getString(1));
                        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    return arrayList;
                }
            }

    // StationDetails Activity
    public class StationDetails extends ActionBarActivity {
        private ListView station_list_view;
         StationDataBase stationDataBase;
         ArrayList<String> arrayList;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.station_details_activity);
            stationDataBase=new StationDataBase(this);
            stationDataBase.getWritableDatabase();
            station_list_view = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.station_listview);
            String getjsonData = getJSONData(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(getjsonData);
                JSONArray trainResultObject = jsonobject.getJSONArray("result");
                for (int i = 0; i < trainResultObject.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject station_json_object = trainResultObject
                            .getJSONObject(i);
                    String station_code = station_json_object.getString("code");
                    String station_name = station_json_object.getString("name");
                    Log.e("Station", "Name" + station_name);
                    Log.e("Station", "code" + station_code);
                    //stationDataBase.insert(new StationData(station_name,station_code));
                    stationDataBase.insertData(station_code, station_name);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*arrayList=stationDataBase.getData();
            Log.e("ArrayList", "Listview"+arrayList.size());*/

        }

        private String getJSONData(Context applicationContext) {
            String getjson = null;
            try {
                InputStream is = applicationContext.getAssets().open(
                        "stationdetails.txt");
                int size = is.available();
                byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
                is.read(buffer);
                is.close();
                getjson = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return getjson;
        }

    }
// Here my logcat errors Logcat Errors    
06-05 09:33:19.563: E/DATA BASE CREATED(14003): CREATEDCREATE TABLE StaionTable(trainCode TEXT,trainStationName TEXT)
06-05 09:33:19.683: E/Station(14003): NameNew Delhi
06-05 09:33:19.683: E/Station(14003): codeNDLS
06-05 09:33:19.683: E/code(14003): insert into dbNDLS
06-05 09:33:19.683: E/code(14003): insert into dbNew Delhi
06-05 09:33:19.693: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=NDLS KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=New Delhi
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/Station(14003): NameMumbai Central
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/Station(14003): codeBCT
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/code(14003): insert into dbBCT
06-05 09:33:19.723: E/code(14003): insert into dbMumbai Central
06-05 09:33:19.733: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=BCT KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=Mumbai Central
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/Station(14003): NameGuntakal JN
06-05 09:33:19.773: E/Station(14003): codeGTL
06-05 09:33:19.783: E/code(14003): insert into dbGTL
06-05 09:33:19.783: E/code(14003): insert into dbGuntakal JN
06-05 09:33:19.783: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=GTL KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=Guntakal JN
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/Station(14003): NameAnantapur
06-05 09:33:19.813: E/Station(14003): codeATP
06-05 09:33:19.823: E/code(14003): insert into dbATP
06-05 09:33:19.823: E/code(14003): insert into dbAnantapur
06-05 09:33:19.823: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=ATP KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=Anantapur
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/Station(14003): NameSecendrabad
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/Station(14003): codeSEC
06-05 09:33:19.873: E/code(14003): insert into dbSEC
06-05 09:33:19.883: E/code(14003): insert into dbSecendrabad
06-05 09:33:19.883: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.943: D/dalvikvm(14003): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 7% free 3300K/3544K, paused 26ms, total 34ms
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=SEC KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=Secendrabad
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/Station(14003): NameKachiguda
06-05 09:33:19.943: E/Station(14003): codeKCG
06-05 09:33:19.953: E/code(14003): insert into dbKCG
06-05 09:33:19.953: E/code(14003): insert into dbKachiguda
06-05 09:33:19.953: E/SQLiteLog(14003): (1) table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): Error inserting KEY_TRAIN_CODE=KCG KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME=Kachiguda
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table StaionTable has no column named KEY_TRAIN_CODE (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO StaionTable(KEY_TRAIN_CODE,KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME) VALUES (?,?)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDataBase.insertData(StationDataBase.java:59)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.example.trainroutes.StationDetails.onCreate(StationDetails.java:41)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
06-05 09:33:19.973: E/SQLiteDatabase(14003):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in yout insertData method that the column name was wrong

```
public void insertData(String station_code, String name) {
                    SQLiteDatabase dataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    // values.put("id", id);
                    values.put(KEY_TRAIN_CODE, station_code);
                    values.put(KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME, name);
                    Log.e("code", "insert into db" + station_code);
                    Log.e("code", "insert into db" + name);
                    dataBase.insert(Data_Base_Table_Name, null, values);
                }
```

`KEY_TRAIN_CODE`, `KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME` is variable  your real column names are `"trainCode"` and same as `"StaionTable"` so modify the code like abvove.

**EDIT:**

You are getting an error no column name right. so need to check your column name. Here you declare like this `public static final String KEY_TRAIN_CODE = "trainCode";` So when the create table query runs your column name crated as `trainCode` not "`KEY_TRAIN_CODE`". And when you are try to insert data "`KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME`" you use like this. That means your column name is `KEY_TRAIN_STATION_NAME`. That is the issue.

Comment: Hi Amsheer , can u please explain the answer where i went wrong

Comment: Check my edit. If you still have any questions pls ask

Comment: Hi Amsheer,i my code how to check database is empty or not.if empty insert data into database one time only.because here i am getting data from json thats y insert data one time only please help

Comment: There is a way to do that. Accept and lose this question and ask new question in SO

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> values.put("KEY_TRAIN_CODE", station_code);
> ```

Don't quote your column name constant names. Change to

```
values.put(KEY_TRAIN_CODE, station_code);
```

and apply similar changes everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be inserting into the database.

When you call your INSERT statement you should specify a table *inside* that database.

For example,

```
INSERT INTO StationTable VALUES ('NDLS', 'New Delhi')
```